# disable Internet explorer close button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, c#-4.0

I have a requirement wherin the IE browser should be disabled from being closed when the ajax modal popup is shown inside the page for a buisness need.Kindly let us know the feasability for the same or options to resolve the needs.

Comment: Would'nt that be great for spammers, if you could just disable closing the browser. Not annoying at all. This is of course not possible for obvious reasons.

Comment: _".Kindly let us know the feasability for the same or options to resolve the needs."_ - you want something, you should show research effort for it. Search "kiosk mode".

Answer (score 3):

It's **NOT POSSIBLE** to disable close button in any of the modern browsers.

If all that you are looking for is to keep users in your page, then i would suggest using the window.onbeforeunload JavaScript event

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){ return 'Do you want to leave ?';}
```

It's supported in all major browsers by asking users a question as to whether they want to leave in the middle of a critical operation.

Here is a reference article to get you started[Using the OnBeforeUnload JavaScript Event](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/insights/825556-using-onbeforeunload-javascript-event)

Comment: yes this we tried. But we need to show the alert message when they try to close the browser moreover it is showing the existing "Are you sure you want to leave " when we use this code snippet. <script> window.onbeforeunload=function() { window.alert("Hai"); return false; } </script>

Comment: The window.onbeforeuload is implemented different way in different browsers. But yes this event will be called even when you click the close button of browser, and can be canceled.

Comment: Dont put "window.alert("Hai");" just return a string. Rest browser will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can not disable the browser's close button , but yes you can capture the browser's close button with the help of Jquery

Comment: if so can i stop the browfer from being closed.